# Access data in underlying forms that are embedded as collection

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I currently work at a webshop and want to build the page with the `Cart`. I created a `CartType` which allows the user to set the delivery address. It also has a field for the products. Since you can change the quantity of the products I need a new form for every product. So I stumbled upon the [CollectionType](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/collection.html)

My Cart looks like this

```
<?php
namespace tzfrs\AppBundle\Form\Type;

use tzfrs\AppBundle\Model\Cart;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class CartType
 * @package tzfrs\AppBundle\Form\Type
 */
class CartType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Other forms
        $builder->add('products', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ProductType::class,
            'label' => false,
        ]);

    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Cart::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, inside the `ProductType` I want to add the `quantity` field

`$builder->add('quantity', ProductQuantity::class);`

however, inside the `buildForm` of my custom `PRoductQuantity` I want to access data from the current product, because the product holds a counter of how many units can be ordered at one. However, the `options` array from the `buildForm` does not have any data.

I have a similar implementation on the product detail page, but since I pass the `product` there I can access the data. However, in these embedded Collections, I don't know how I can access data of that field. How would I set data in embedded collection of forms?

Comment: Could you add your ProductType::class ?